# Emit server to client data in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io, emit

I can't emit data to client from server, I get undefined on `console.log` for res variable in client js codes.

This is my server codes

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const path = require('path')

// View
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/view')))

// Homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname + '/view/index.html'))
})

// Socket connection
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  console.log('----------------------------')
  console.log('connected an user')
  console.log('----------------------------')

  socket.emit('connect', 'datax')

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnected')
    console.log('----------------------------')
  })

})

// Server run
server.listen(3000)
```

and this is my client codes

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  'use strict';

  var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

  socket.on('connect', function(res) {

    console.log('connected');

    console.log(res);

  })
  .on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnect');
  });

});
```

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the socket io emit cheat sheet.. [here](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/). Scroll to bottom and you will see that there are some reserved words that cant be used to emit custom events. connect is one such word. Try emitting some other event and listen to that on the client side.